# Python Error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, html, tags, typeerror, python-3.3

I have this segment of code:

```
count_words = input("Put in your favorite word, and then press the hidden button(SPOILER: IT'S ENTER!):")
split_Geonotes = Geonotes.replace ("\n", " "). split(".")
print (" Total number of words:", len (Geonotes.split() ) )

print("Total number of sentences:", len (Geonotes.split(".") ) )
print("Total number of periods:", Geonotes.count(".") )
print("you typed:", count_words)
print("There are:", Geonotes.count(count_words), "instances of", count_words)
split_Geonotes.sort()
print(split_Geonotes)
print("The number of elements in the HTML code:", len (split_Geonotes) )

for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    print(split_Geonotes(i) )
```

that begets the error shown in the title.
According to the full error it happens at print(i)
Can someone explain to me what's wrong?
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to index the list `split_Geonotes` on the last line.  You need to use square brackets `[...]` for this:

```
print(split_Geonotes[i])
```

Parenthesis `(...)` are for calling a function; when you place them after `split_Geonotes`, Python will try to call the list:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>>> lst[0]
1
>>>
```